# css style php as function

Tags: php, css, function

While i am still learning css html5 and Jquery, combined with the information from the internet, i came up with a idea to program the css in to different chapters, and call them in to the head section when need it.

from my understanding, via google it is faster to load css styles in the head as a `<style></style>`.
This way i will only have the css at the page that i need, and it will be better readable for me, becouse i dont use html css styling in dreamweaver anyway.
My css is now so big it is taking tomutch time to find it all.
even with dreamweaver search box.

Does any one have experience with this, or see any problems i might incounter?

Thanx in advance..

Comment: load the css from server, instead from google, break the css into two smaller sheets??may be this help..

Comment: While it is true that loading CSS in `<style>` tags is "faster", that's only because it avoids an HTTP request. However, unless you have a bounce rate of 100%, ie. people actually stay on your site for more than a single page? It should go in a separate `<link rel="stylesheet" />` because of this wonderful thing called the cache ;)

Comment: I am not sure if the cache only aplys to rel="stylesheet" becouse when i use cache, it also often remebers text, very anoying when you just updated the text area, and it is showing the old lines, also if i do this correctly, i am pretty sure the styling wil decrease sufficiently, for disableing cache, but i am not sure also how <style></style> will react to @media querys combined with php programming/my unique project.

Comment: I got a error the last time i try'd this way, thats why i cancled it.
the same error pop upped again today, after saving, the error disappeared.
So where off to this way....cache is enabled, text is set to acces plus 0 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to create structure if you're working in a big php project is to save a blank html page, load the existing css on to that page, use the css options/panels in dreamweaver and load the body parts you need in there.
If your using a dynamic css location link, other wise, i think dreamweaver will do just fine in php.
Not sure becouse i never used it that way...

Situation
i try'd to make more sence doing it this way, but i have just put everything back, becouse i got a unknown error, did not investigate it further. And the `<style></style>` has the highest level of design, meaning all the rules that where set, will be overwritten, things will get complicated fast if you start moving parts aspecialy if have a multi css styling site, so it is not recommended if you already have a big project, do it from the start...

Edit * 27-11-2015

I found the solution, i am using classes to slowely but surely replace the css file...